# Algorithm for Generating Unique Random Numbers within a Range without Using a List

Tags: php, algorithm, random

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm in PHP to generate unique random numbers within a specified range (start = 0 to end = 0xFFFFFFFF) without using a list to store all possible numbers. I've explored various approaches, but each seems to require maintaining a list of all possible numbers, which isn't feasible for large ranges due to memory constraints. When all possible numbers have been returned, then the entire number range can be used again.

Is there a way to accomplish this without storing all possible numbers in memory? I've considered using hash functions or permutation algorithms, but I'm unsure of the best approach or if there's a more efficient solution available. Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Linear Congruential Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) are one easy way, and in your case so are [Linear Feedback Shift Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). How good does the randomness need to be?

Comment: You should say _why_ you need this, as the answer will be heavily dependent on that.

Comment: There's no way to ensure that all the numbers are unique without keeping a list of all the previous numbers that were generated. There's nothing that prevents a RNG from producing the same number multiple times.

Comment: Instead of storing them in memory, use a database.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It doesn't have to be truly random, but it shouldn't be directly predictable either.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a pseudo-random number generator, you want a permutation of 2^32 numbers. You could just code some complicated bijective function from 32bit unsigned integers to the same, keeping some internal state for the next request etc.

Comment: @SimonGoater maybe this is the right direction

Comment: @Barmar in a bad situation, i have to store 4294967295 entries, many stuff...

Comment: And if you want help with @SimonGoater's idea, I think [math.se] or [security.se] would be the place to ask. You're looking for a function that produces a unique result for each 32-bit input, but isn't easily reversible.

Comment: @Barmar Why " but isn't easily reversible."? Linear Congruential Generator produces a unique result for each 32-bit input, and is extremely easy to reverse

Comment: Linear Congruential Generator is your friend. Looks for proper conditions (aka Hull–Dobell Theorem) and you are all set

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I was thinking that if you can reverse it, you know what the current element of the sequence is, and can increment that to get the next value

Comment: Well, you need to know constants of the LCG, not just the current RV.

Comment: I could provide C++ code in the answer for 64bit LCG with inverse.

Comment: Mr. @President, I see from your bio you are retired, but of course everyone knows that. I thought I was one of SO's elder statesmen, but I am but a pup when compared to you. I was thinking of you, incidentally, on a recent trip to the Lone Star State to visit my great, great, grandchildren.

Comment: @Barmar: Indeed, LCGs are not secure by any measure. With a few outputs you can recover the current state and all the constants. But, they are simple, fast, and often good enough™. But Volker wants them unpredictable, so they are not good enough for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple/naive solution that would survive scrutiny of the average person, but immediately fall apart under the scrutiny of any determined person, would be to simply scramble the bits according to a defined key.

```php
class ShuffleKey {
    
    private $key;
    
    public static function newKey(int $size=32) {
        $key = range(1,$size);
        shuffle($key);
        return new self($key);
    }
    
    public function __construct(array $key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }
    
    public function getKey(bool $invert=false) {
        if( $invert ) {
            return array_flip($this->key);
        } else {
            return $this->key;
        }
    }
}

class IntegerShuffler {
    public function __construct(protected Shufflekey $key) {}
    
    public function shuffle($in) {
        return $this->_shuffle($in, $this->key->getKey());
    }
    
    public function unshuffle($in) {
        return $this->_shuffle($in, $this->key->getKey(true));
    }
    
    protected function _shuffle($in, $key) {
        $out = 0;
        foreach( $key as $offset => $transform ) {
            $out = $this->setBitAt($out, $transform, $this->getBitAt($in, $offset));
        }
        return $out;
    }
    
    protected function getBitAt(int $value, int $position) {
        return ( $value >> $position ) & 1;
    }
    
    protected function setBitAt(int $value, int $position, int $bit) {
        return $value | ( $bit << $position );
    }
}

// json_encode(ShuffleKey::newKey()->getKey())
$key = json_decode('[20,22,31,27,6,32,8,21,11,4,25,9,3,13,23,30,12,18,17,2,7,1,16,28,10,26,14,24,19,29,15,5]', true);

$shuf = new IntegerShuffler(new ShuffleKey($key));

var_dump(
    $t = $shuf->shuffle(1234567890),
    $shuf->unshuffle($t)
);
```

Output:

```
int(291931600)
int(1234567890)
```

In this way you can just run through the range sequentially, scrambling as you go, as well as being able to "unshuffle" arbitrary numbers.

If you need something that actually stands up to even the minimum amount of scrutiny, then you should be looking at something like a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) or [Linear Feedback Shift Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) as suggested by "President James K. Polk" in the comments. [Note: The commenter, not the 11th US President.]

If you need "proper" security, then you must descend into the [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and/or [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/) sections of StackExchange for suitably strong methods, as suggested by Barmar in the comments.

Comment: i have accepted this post, so here is a working code aside!

Answer (score 1):

0xFFFFFFFF is 32 bits. One solution would be to use a 32 bit encryption, and encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... with the same key. Encryption is guaranteed to be one-to-one so as long as the inputs are unique then the outputs will also be unique. All you need to record is the encryption key and where you are in the input sequence.

For a different ordering of the numbers use a different key.

For a 32 bit encryption either use Hasty Pudding cipher or write your own simple [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher). Obviously, you won't need the decryption part.

Comment: An obvious question is how well this would do when subjected to [randomness tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test).

Comment: The output is designed not to include repeats, so it will likely fail some randomness tests. Truly random output will contain repeats, which a good randomness test will detect. The output is a random permutation of the input numbers, so is not itself random output.

Comment: seems to be a valid solution, is there are an known PHP implementation? this is a python way: https://github.com/neilsagarwal/hpc

Comment: I do not know enough about PHP. Unfortunately Hasty Pudding cipher is not common in cipher libraries, so it might be difficult to find a Python version. Probably easier to write your own simple 32 bit Feistel cipher in Python.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason you would want to double check the existing list of numbers, is because the chance of collisions is never zero, and this chance increases every time you generate a new value.

Storing in RAM isn't typically necessary, but they do need to be stored somewhere so that you can refer to them as needed. I suggest using a database or an efficient caching solution such as Redis for this purpose.

I've hypothesised what this code may look like, although it's untested.

```php
/**
 * Generates a number and verifies that it is unique.
 * 
 * @throws \Exception when a unique value cannot be found within the specified number of retries.
 * Wrap within a try/catch, or change to `E_USER_WARNING`.
 * 
 * @param int $retries The total number of retries if collisions are found.
 * Any negative number can be used for unlimited retries.
 * A zero value will automatically cause the error to be thrown.
 * @return int A number between 0 and 0xFFFFFFFF.
 */
function generate_unique_number($retries = 10): int {
    do {
        if (0 === $retries--) {
            user_error('The maximum number of retries reached, so this number may not be unique.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        $number = random_int(0, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    while (!number_is_unique($number));
    return $number;
}

/**
 * Determines whether a number has been used via Redis.
 * 
 * @throws \Exception when $remember is set to true, but the new number cannot be saved.
 * Wrap within a try/catch, or change to `E_USER_WARNING`.
 * 
 * @param int $number A randomly generated number.
 * @param bool $remember When set to true, this function will also store the supplied number.
 * @return bool TRUE if the number is unique, or FALSE if it was found using Redis.
 */
function number_is_unique($number, $remember = true): bool {
    global $redis; // Redis needs to be initialised elsewhere.
    if ($redis->get($number)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($remember) {
        $set = $redis->set($number, 1);
        // Can return the value of $set instead.
        if (!$set) {
            user_error('Unable to store number for future reference.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```